# Typescript compiled code doesn't work with Obfuscators

Tags: typescript, gulp

I have a node project written in Typescript.  I am trying to use obfuscator via Gulp.  But it doesn't seem to work:

Here is my gulp file:

```
const { series, src, dest, task } = require('gulp');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const javascriptObfuscator = require('gulp-javascript-obfuscator-fixed');

function CopyFile(){
    return src(['debug/*.js','debug/*.json'])
        .pipe(dest('dist'));
};
function Obfuscate(){
    return src('dist/*.js')
        .pipe(javascriptObfuscator())
        .pipe(uglify());
};
task("Release", series(CopyFile, Obfuscate));
```

Here is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "debug",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

So the order is, typescript compile, then copy to dist, then obfuscate.  Here is the error I am getting:

```
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: keyword «const»
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to minify, then obfuscate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As on https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js:

> - `uglify-js` only supports JavaScript (ECMAScript 5).
> - To minify ECMAScript 2015 or above, transpile using tools like Babel.

`const` is an [ES6 ("ES2015") language feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Specifications), allowed because you set `"target": "es6"`. You can set the `target` to `es5`, or use a different tool.

Answer (score 0):

It means that uglify doesn't speak es6.  Try this instead:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify-es